# wget: Retrieving a list of URLs when modifying input data file on the fly

Tags: awk, wget, cut

This issue is currently driving me up the wall.
It just does not work as it should.

I have a file **inp** with audio samples to download where I preserved the internal ID number by parsing some other location of the HTML source file to get rid of the internal (hex) filename, looking like this:

```
http://whatever.site/data/samples/hexfilename1.mp3 12345.mp3
http://whatever.site/data/samples/hexfilename2.mp3 12346.mp3
http://whatever.site/data/samples/hexfilename3.mp3 12347.mp3
http://whatever.site/data/samples/hexfilename4.mp3 12348.mp3 
http://whatever.site/data/samples/hexfilename5.mp3 12349.mp3
```

As I only need the first part on each line, I've tried `awk` or alternatively `cut` to strip the rest, but on the fly:

```
$ wget -nc -i $(cut -f1 '-d ' inp)
```

respectively

```
$ wget -nc -i $(awk 'print $1' inp)
```

But it will download all the mp3 files, then grind for a short while, and something very strange will happen:

```
--2014-09-01 14:27:25--  http://whatever.site/data/samples/ID3%04
```

Ugh. It is exactly what you're thinking it is: indeed the first bytes of the binary mp3 file that `wget` is trying to download, after it is finished downloading the regular ones (and supposed to terminate). But why does it happen?
If I go the clumsy way by creating a **inp2** temporary file for `wget` and using it with the `-i` parameter, it works:

```
$ cat inp | awk '{print $1}' > inp2
```

Why is there so much difference when *inp* gets modified on the fly and passed directly to `wget`?
The most interesting thing is that the on-the-fly variant won't work with either `awk` or `cut`, so neither of both tools are to blame.

Comment: What happens if you swap them over: `awk '{print $1}' inp | wget -i -` ?

Comment: Do what @garethTheRed said. -i takes a file name as an argument (in your example, the first URL in your list) and reads it to get a list of URLs to retrieve.

Comment: Alternatively, I guess `wget -nc -i <$(cut -f1 -d' ' inp)` will work, if you're using bash.

Comment: @garethTheRed You're a marvel. Doing them in this order works. Thank you very much. But thanks as well to Mark for the alternate solution, which works if you use `wget -nc -i <(cut -f1 -d' ' inp)`. No dollars here. :)

Comment: @syntaxerror If you found a solution, it's totally OK to add and accept your own answer. (There might be a minimum time limit until you can accept it though.)

Comment: Well, the basic problem is that there were two very useful comments which ought to have been posted as answers. However I guess this has been done on purpose, because both of the commenters were not entirely sure since they could not "live-test" it at the moment they posted it. So both of them or just one may turn theirs into an answer, and I'll put the checkmark on it. But not on my own one, that's silly.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it didn't work is bad syntax:

```
wget -nc -i $(cut -f1 '-d ' inp)
```

...the problem is the `-i` switch expects either:

1. a local text file containing list of URLs
2. a remote text file containing list of URLs
3. a remote HTML file containing list of files local to it.

But the code above gives `-i http://whatever.site/data/samples/hexfilename1.mp3`, which isn't a text or HMTL file.  `man wget` says:

```
COLUMNS=72 man wget | grep -m1 -A 22 '\-i '
   -i file
   --input-file=file
       Read URLs from a local or external file.  If - is specified
       as file, URLs are read from the standard input.  (Use ./-
       to read from a file literally named -.)

       If this function is used, no URLs need be present on the
       command line.  If there are URLs both on the command line
       and in an input file, those on the command lines will be
       the first ones to be retrieved.  If --force-html is not
       specified, then file should consist of a series of URLs,
       one per line.

       However, if you specify --force-html, the document will be
       regarded as html.  In that case you may have problems with
       relative links, which you can solve either by adding "<base
       href="url">" to the documents or by specifying --base=url
       on the command line.

       If the file is an external one, the document will be
       automatically treated as html if the Content-Type matches
       text/html.  Furthermore, the file's location will be
       implicitly used as base href if none was specified.
```

Fixes include:

1. Using *stdin* for the `-i` parameter as per [*garethTheRed*'s
   comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153152/wget-retrieving-a-list-of-urls-when-modifying-input-data-file-on-the-fly#comment250025_153152):

   ```
   cut -d' ' -f1 inp | wget -nc -i -
   ```
2. Or this `bash` centric method, which is about one byte off from what
   was originally intended, as per [*syntaxerror*'s comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153152/wget-retrieving-a-list-of-urls-when-modifying-input-data-file-on-the-fly#comment250073_153152) :

   ```
   wget -nc -i <(cut -f1 '-d ' inp)
   ```